# Find $f'$ if $f(x) = \lfloor{x} \rfloor$ - solution critique

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Find $f'$ if $f(x) = \lfloor{x} \rfloor$

This question is from Spivak's Calculus. So using the definition of a function differentiable at a specific point I treated the expression as the following:

1. If $a$ is an integer:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a - a}{h} = 0$$

2. If $a$ is not an integer. In this case I treated $a$ as $a = x + D$ where $D$ is the fractional part of $a$. As such:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lfloor{a + h}\rfloor - \lfloor{a} \rfloor}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x - D + h) - (x - D)}{h} = 1$$

I just rewrote the floor expression in terms of its decimal parts. Now the solution provided by the textbook says that $f'(a) = 0$ for $a$ not an integer and $f'(a)$ is not defined for $a$ an integer. I feel my approach is right. It just flows directly from the definition. So if wrong what did I approach incorrectly?

Comment: Should the derivative not be $0$ when $a\notin\Bbb Z$?  The graph is rather intuitive.

Comment: For sufficiently small $h$, $\lfloor a+h\rfloor=\lfloor x+D+h\rfloor=x$ and $\lfloor a\rfloor=\lfloor x+D\rfloor=x$. Thus the limit for $a \not\in \Bbb{Z}$ will be $0$.

Comment: $f$ is not continuous at the integers hence not differentiable. $f$ is locally constant in between the integers hence $f$ is differentiable ther with derivative zero.

Comment: @copper.hat your absolutely right and I actually did prove the continuity earlier on too....smh. Could I not treat the integer points as right and left hand derivatives?

Comment: When $a \in \Bbb{Z}$, then $\lfloor a+h \rfloor$ need not be $a$. In particular, if $h>0$, then it will be $a$, but when $h<0$, then it will be $a-1$. So the first limit you computed as $0$, actually doesn't exist.